# Typescript interface with string attribute AND dictionary of arrays

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I am trying to type objects that would look like :

```
{
    name: "toto",
    index: [ 1, 2, 3],
    foo: [ "foo1", foo2", "foo3"],
    bar: [ "bar1", "bar2","bar3"]
}
```

I know for sure that I will have the name and index attributes, however I don't know whether I will have one or x "foo" attributes.

I tried the following interface:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    name: string;
    index: Array<number>;
    [seriesname: string]: Array<string>;
}
```

The error is thrown for the row:

```
name: string;
```

> Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'string[]'.ts(2411)

I seems to me that all my attributes MUST be compatible with the dictionary I described with the row:

```
[seriesname: string]: Array<string>;
```

Which means I cannot type my object like this. Is there a way to do it ? (I don't want to modify the object, as I receive it from another application.)

Comment: Can you paste your whole code ? just by seeing the interface i cant tell what wrong you are doing

Comment: Do you know what possible "seriesname" there are, or is it completely free-form?

Comment: I don't know what seriesname there will be, but I know that their value will always be of type Array<string>

Comment: I don't think it is relevant to paste my whole  code, because the vscode Typescript linter reacts when I modify the interface

Comment: this question has been marked as duplicate, I used the information in the other post to solve my problem, thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all your arrays will of type either `number` or `string`, your interface could serve both and add the types to the `name` property:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    name: string | Array<number> | Array<string>;
    index: string | Array<number> | Array<string>;
    [seriesname: string]: string | Array<string> | Array<number>;
}
```

The solution above is detailed explanation here: [typescript-book](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/de70ce929b992de89b5abd9befa7007139e90fd6/docs/types/index-signatures.md#all-members-must-conform-to-the-string-index-signature)

This could get quite messy, depending on different types and properties though.

Comment: this seems to work, but don't we lose the point of typing here ? I would have to take into account the fact that my seriesname attributes could be strings (rather than arrays) everywhere in my code.

Comment: for example, I would get the following error : "Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string | string[] | number[]'."

Comment: @PleaseHelp this is true, this just shifts the problem further down the line, as you could then use `instanceof` or `typeof` depending on your style